# I cannot find the source of the error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'

Tags: json, flutter

I am new to flutter programming and I am trying to create a program based on a tutorial. My code does not have errors  but when I run it, it throws an error type 'String' is not a subtype of type 'int' of 'index'. This is my code. I think the error lies on the rows.

```
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Readings {
  final int id;
  final double temperature, humidity;
  final String FanStatus, MistStatus;
  final DateTime Time;


  Readings(
      {required this.id,
       required this.temperature,
      required this.humidity,
      required this.FanStatus,
      required this.MistStatus,
      required this.Time});

  factory Readings.fromJson(Map<String,dynamic> json) {
    return Readings(
      id: json['id'],
      temperature: json['temperature'],
      humidity: json['humidity'],
      FanStatus: json['FanStatus'],
      MistStatus: json['MistStatus'],
      Time: json['Time'],
    );
  }
}

Future<List<Readings>> fetchSummary() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://mushroomdroid.online/dbscript-1.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var parsed = json.decode(response.body);
    // print(parsed.length);
    List jsonResponse = parsed["id"] as List;

    return jsonResponse.map((job) => Readings.fromJson(job)).toList();
  } else {
    print('Error, Could not load Data.');
    throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
  }
}

class RecordsPage extends StatefulWidget {
  const RecordsPage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _RecordsPage createState() => _RecordsPage();
}

class _RecordsPage extends State<RecordsPage> {
  final controller = ScrollController();
  double offset = 0;

  late Future<List<Readings>> _func;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _func = fetchSummary();
    controller.addListener(onScroll);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onScroll() {
    setState(() {
      offset = (controller.hasClients) ? controller.offset : 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Readings>>(
        future: _func,
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Readings>? data = snapshot.data;
            // print(data);
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Worldwide Cases ->'),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:10.0
                    ),
                    child: Center(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: DataTable(
                          sortColumnIndex: 0,
                          sortAscending: true,
                          columns: [
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Country',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: false,
                              tooltip: "Country Name",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Total Confirmed',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.orange.shade900,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "Total Confirmed",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'New Confirmed',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "New Confirmed",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Total Deaths',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.red.shade700,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "Total Deaths",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'New Deaths',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "New Deaths",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Total Recovered',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "Total Recovered",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'New Recovered',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "New Recovered",
                            ),
                          ],
                          rows: data!
                              .map(
                                (country) => DataRow(
                              cells: [
                                DataCell(
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 100,
                                    child: Text(
                                      country.id.toString(),
                                      softWrap: true,
                                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                      style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  SizedBox(
                                    width: 60.0,
                                    child: Center(
                                      child: Text(
                                        country.Time.toString(),
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      country.temperature.toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      country.humidity.toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      country.FanStatus.toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                DataCell(
                                  Center(
                                    child: Text(
                                      country.MistStatus.toString(),
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          )
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // SizedBox(height: 500),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text(
                'An Error Occured!',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
              ),
              content: Text(
                "${snapshot.error}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Go Back',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          }
          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text('This may take some time..')
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is the tutorial I am learning from:

https://github.com/Dhruvpolaris/covid-19_project/blob/master/lib/widgets/details_screen.dart

Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: because your variable is list that need int to access it, map can use string to access it. that error because you force map to list. try print runtimeType of your variable before the error and replace one of it, it must have same type.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I'm sorry I am a total beginner. Please refer to the link I posted, Is there any difference with my List? We both have mixed variable types in our list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few issues here. The error is telling you that you have mismatched data types.

If you look at the json response

```
[
  {
    "id": "1322",
    "temperature": "29.92",
    "humidity": "69.73",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "ON \r\n",
    "Time": "2022-05-10 11:38:46"
  },
  {
    "id": "1321",
    "temperature": "30.02",
    "humidity": "69.47",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "ON \r\n",
    "Time": "2022-05-10 11:28:46"
  },
  {
    "id": "1320",
    "temperature": "29.98",
    "humidity": "69.19",
    "FanStatus": "ON",
    "MistStatus": "ON \r\n",
    "Time": "2022-05-10 11:18:45"
  },
...
]
```

You'll see that all values in the key/value pairs are of type `String`.

Then when you look at your model

```
class Readings {
  final int id;
  final double temperature, humidity;
  final String FanStatus, MistStatus;
  final DateTime Time;
```

You see that you're trying to assign a `String` to an `int`, `double`, and `DateTime`.

So first step is to correct the data types in your model. Since you're converting it all to `String` in your widget I'm changing it all to `String` except the `DateTime`. The other option would be to keep `int` and `double` and use `int.parse(json['id'] as String)` etc...

```
class Readings {
  final String id;
  final String temperature, humidity;
  final String FanStatus, MistStatus;
  final DateTime Time;

  Readings(
      {required this.id,
      required this.temperature,
      required this.humidity,
      required this.FanStatus,
      required this.MistStatus,
      required this.Time});

  factory Readings.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return Readings(
      id: json['id'],
      temperature: json['temperature'],
      humidity: json['humidity'],
      FanStatus: json['FanStatus'],
      MistStatus: json['MistStatus'],
      Time: DateTime.parse(json['Time'] as String),
    );
  }
}
```

Next, this line of your `fetchSummary` method.

```
List jsonResponse = parsed["id"] as List;
```

Is trying to access a field that doesn't exist. There's no field in the root of the response called `id`, they're all nested in the `maps` in the response. It all can be simplified to this.

```
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var parsed = json.decode(response.body) as List;
    return parsed.map((job) => Readings.fromJson(job)).toList();
  }
```

You also can just pass in the `fetchSummary` method straight into the `FutureBuilder`, you don't need to define a separate variable.

```
FutureBuilder<List<Readings>>(
        future: fetchSummary(), // just pass in the Future method
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Readings>? data = snapshot.data;
```

Lastly, the number of `cells` in `DataTable` needs to match the number of `columns`. So to quickly get this to build without error I just duplicated the last cell as a quick fix but you can figure out what you really want to put there.

So that all would look like this.

```
class _RecordsPage extends State<RecordsPage> {
  final controller = ScrollController();
  double offset = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    controller.addListener(onScroll);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  void onScroll() {
    setState(() {
      offset = (controller.hasClients) ? controller.offset : 0;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: FutureBuilder<List<Readings>>(
        future: fetchSummary(),
        builder: (ctx, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            List<Readings>? data = snapshot.data;
            // print(data);
            return SingleChildScrollView(
              scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Center(
                    child: Text('Worldwide Cases ->'),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                    child: Center(
                      child: SingleChildScrollView(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                        child: DataTable(
                          sortColumnIndex: 0,
                          sortAscending: true,
                          columns: [
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Country',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 18.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: false,
                              tooltip: "Country Name",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Total Confirmed',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.orange.shade900,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "Total Confirmed",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'New Confirmed',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "New Confirmed",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Total Deaths',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.red.shade700,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "Total Deaths",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'New Deaths',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "New Deaths",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'Total Recovered',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.green,
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "Total Recovered",
                            ),
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text(
                                'New Recovered',
                                style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: 16.0,
                                ),
                              ),
                              numeric: true,
                              tooltip: "New Recovered",
                            ),
                          ],
                          rows: data!
                              .map(
                                (country) => DataRow(
                                  cells: [
                                    DataCell(
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 100,
                                        child: Text(
                                          country.id.toString(),
                                          softWrap: true,
                                          overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      SizedBox(
                                        width: 60.0,
                                        child: Center(
                                          child: Text(
                                            country.Time.toString(),
                                            style: TextStyle(
                                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          country.temperature,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          country.humidity,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          country.FanStatus,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          country.MistStatus,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    DataCell(
                                      Center(
                                        child: Text(
                                          country.MistStatus,
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              )
                              .toList(),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  // SizedBox(height: 500),
                ],
              ),
            );
          } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text(
                'An Error Occured!',
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.redAccent,
                ),
              ),
              content: Text(
                "${snapshot.error}",
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.blueAccent,
                ),
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                TextButton(
                  child: Text(
                    'Go Back',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                    ),
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          }
          // By default, show a loading spinner.
          return Center(
            child: Column(
              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: <Widget>[
                CircularProgressIndicator(),
                SizedBox(height: 20),
                Text('This may take some time..')
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

That should clear all your errors.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same issue while working with Firebase, in my case a field in the Firebase console had int instead of a string. In your case, the issue could be this piece here

```
List jsonResponse = parsed["id"].toString() as List;
```

Comment: I tried to remove it, no errors but it still throws the same error when the app runs on the emulator. I have edited the post and included the code. Please look into it sir.

Answer (score 0):

Please check Below code.

```
class Readings {
  String? id;
  String? temperature;
  String? humidity;
  String? fanStatus;
  String? mistStatus;
  String? time;

  Readings(
      {this.id,
        this.temperature,
        this.humidity,
        this.fanStatus,
        this.mistStatus,
        this.time});

  Readings.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    id = json['id'];
    temperature = json['temperature'];
    humidity = json['humidity'];
    fanStatus = json['FanStatus'];
    mistStatus = json['MistStatus'];
    time = json['Time'];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> data = new Map<String, dynamic>();
    data['id'] = this.id;
    data['temperature'] = this.temperature;
    data['humidity'] = this.humidity;
    data['FanStatus'] = this.fanStatus;
    data['MistStatus'] = this.mistStatus;
    data['Time'] = this.time;
    return data;
  }
}
```

Method code

```
Future<List<Readings>> fetchSummary() async {
  final response = await http.get(Uri.parse('http://mushroomdroid.online/dbscript-1.php'));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    var data = response.body.replaceAll('\r\n', '\\r\\n');
    var parsed = json.decode(data);
    return parsed;
  } else {
    print('Error, Could not load Data.');
    throw Exception('Failed to load Data');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but the error is still there. Also, the variables are from the database. Does it affect the outcome when I change the variable names and types?